# SQL Server inner join subquery with alias on where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I thought this was going to be easy when asked to do it but it has been noogling my noggin'.
I want to use a value from a previous join to apply to the where clause on a subquery of a subsequent join.
For now I have hardcoded a value but that obvious can't stay like that.
Here's what I have so far;

```
select
       SU.SUName
     , Q.[Name] AS [QualName]
     , DSP.EmployeeID AS [EmployeeID]
     , E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS [FullName]
  from SchedulingUnit            AS SU
 inner join StaffingProfile      AS SP  on SU.UnitID = SP.UnitID
 inner join DailyStaffingProfile AS DSP on SP.ID = DSP.ID
 inner join (SELECT QualID, [Name] FROM Qualifications WHERE QualID = **56**
              UNION
             SELECT BaseQualificationID, [Name]
               from QualificationDependencies AS QD
              inner join Qualifications AS Q ON Q.QualID = QD.QualifiesForID
              WHERE QualifiesForID IN (SELECT QualID FROM Qualifications WHERE QualID = **56** )) 
                                  AS Q ON SP.QualID = Q.QualID
 inner join Employee             AS E   on DSP.EmployeeID = E.EmpID
 where (@UnitID IS NULL OR SU.UnitID = @UnitID)
   and SU.HideInList = 0
   and NOT EXISTS (select * from EQ where EmpID = E.EmpID and SP.QualID = EQ.QualID)
```

I'd like to replace the 2 instances of 56 with SP.QualID ... is that possible?

Comment: Use `APPLY` rather than a `JOIN`.

Comment: Hi Larnu, thanks for the reply but I'm not getting the correct results doing that. I do have a solution though that I'll post

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with that; there is no sample data nor expected results.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `SP.QualID` in the subquery. The `SP.QualID = Q.QualID` after the subquery already does what do you want. Just remove the two `WHERE QualID = 56` in subquery.

Comment: Hi DefconT34, your suggestion didn't yield the correct results, but your suggestion to remove the 56 in the query was a good starting point.  I moved the subquery out to be a CTE and removed the where clause entirely (WHERE QualifiesForID IN (SELECT QualID FROM Qualifications WHERE QualID = **56** ) ... that seems to have done it

Comment: hi Boomer, i'm so happy that you've find a solution of your problems. sorry for the fail of my proposition of solution.  you're make a good choice for CTE usage, it's very good thing to have a good lisibility of your query.